# how to take every 9 lines of file as single record while reading textfile spark/scala RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

how can I parse this data file in spark/scala and take every 9 lines as single record. I need them to rewrite every 9 lines as comma separated.[check this image for the data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttThd.png)

Comment: You should convert your data into json or xml which would make life lot easier

Comment: Hoping you will like the approach here as it was an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Generate from RDD to DF and process as shown below.

The g is group, the k is key to record number which repeats within g. v is your record content. Skip the empty entry somehow. I left the key in, you can strip that out.

Input is a file of 6 lines and I used groups of 3. You can change that to 9 and do the write.df; I have done the heavy lifting.

Then apply this logic and rename the columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

val dfsFilename = "/FileStore/tables/7dxa9btd1477497663691/Text_File_01-880f5.txt"
val readFileRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile(dfsFilename)
val rdd2 = readFileRDD.sliding(3,3).zipWithIndex
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(r => (r._1.zipWithIndex, r._2))
val df = rdd3.toDF("vk","g")

val df2 = df.withColumn("vke", explode($"vk")).drop("vk")
val df3 = df2.withColumn("k", $"vke._2").withColumn("v", $"vke._1").drop("vke")

val result = df3
            .groupBy("g")
            .pivot("k")
            .agg(expr("first(v)"))

result.show()
```

returns:

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  g|                   0|                   1|                   2|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0|The quick brown f...|Here he lays I te...|Gone are the days...|
|  1|  Gosh, what to say.|Hallo, hallo, how...|          I am fine.|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

You could use sliding with 9,10.

Moreover, there is the approach of:

```
val rdd = readFileRDD.coalesce(1).mapPartitions(_.grouped(n))
```

But you must coalesce to 1 and some process the skip record, every tenth. n could be set to 10 and strip the last value out.